# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/net/compatibility/WebAddress.class

Tags: android

Hy! I am having following problem in my Android project

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/net/compatibility/WebAddress.class

I Know this is because of conflict in dependencies. I looked into dependencies but not able to configure which dependencies causing this issue. I am pasting my gradle code bellow

Module 1 :

```
android {
//useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION)
buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

defaultConfig {
    versionCode Integer.parseInt(project.VERSION_CODE)
    versionName project.VERSION_NAME
    minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_MIN_SDK)
    targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
}`sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
    }
    test {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
    }
}`compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7`    }

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
}`lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}

checkstyle {
    ignoreFailures = true
}
buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'`}`dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile project(':webViewMarker')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'`}`
```

Module 2

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`ext {
bintrayRepo = 'maven'
bintrayName = 'folioreader'

publishedGroupId = 'com.folioreader'
libraryName = 'WebViewMarker'
artifact = 'webViewMarker'

libraryDescription = 'An epub reader for Android'

siteUrl = 'https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReader-Android'
gitUrl = 'https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReader-Android.git'

libraryVersion = '0.2.5'

developerId = 'mobisystech'
developerName = 'Folio Reader'
developerEmail = 'mahavir@codetoart.com'

licenseName = 'FreeBSD License'
licenseUrl = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_Documentation_License#License'
allLicenses = ["FreeBSD"]`}`android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    versionCode Integer.parseInt(project.VERSION_CODE)
    versionName project.VERSION_NAME
    minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_MIN_SDK)
    targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}`
}
apply from: '../folioreader/bintray/installv1.gradle'
apply from: '../folioreader/bintray/bintrayv1.gradle'
```

Main Module

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}`}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ebook.stev_ebook"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}
}
repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile project(':folioreader')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:+'
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.3.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please comment this

```
compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
```

Try Rebuilding again. Since it's a third party library , there is a chance that it might be causing the trouble

Comment: Still having same issue

Comment: Your support library version on Main module is 22.2.1 and of Module 1 is 25.0.1 . Make sure both modules use same library version.

Answer (score 0):

It means you are using different version of support and all android libraries for example you are using support library version 25.0.1 in one module and version 22.2.1 in another and of course you should add just one of these library to your dependencies when you add one library in one module you should not add it to build.gradle file of second.

---

Solution : remove duplicate libraries.